# Modification of list item properties using PnP CSOM

Tags: pnp

Is there any place where I can find a straightforward example of how manipulate a list item properties using PnP CSOM Core?

I've been looking for examples and watching videos in the official documentation and I haven't found something clear.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/818 and this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-basic-list-item-operations-using-pnp-powershell/

Comment: Thank you for your comment @SMerchant but that is related to PnP Powershell. I'm trying to do it in C#